# Tableview with 2 columns

Tags: qgis, python, pyqt4

I'm using QlistView to show my names of departement in the studied area after using the 'extract by location' processus:

```
# res=QgsVectorLayer()
    # capture  département inside the studied area :
    res = processing.runalg('qgis:extractbylocation', departementLayer, layerZone, u'intersects', 0, None)
    # Créer une couche vector issue de l'extraction des départements dans la zone
 departementLayer = QgsVectorLayer(res['OUTPUT'], "Departement(s) dans la zone d'etude","ogr")      
    features = ObjectifVilleExtract.departementLayer.getFeatures()
    model3 = QStandardItemModel()
    for feature in features:
        item = QStandardItem(feature['name_dept'])
        item.setCheckable(True)
        .model3.appendRow(item)
        self.dlg.listView.setModel(.model3)
```

Now I would like to show the code for each departement . I know that I can't use "listview" but I have to use 'Qtableview'. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show only two columns, you can make use of the [setHorizontalHeaderItem()](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#setHorizontalHeaderItem) method for your model and then fill each row with values for both columns. The following is an example which could be run from the Python Console but you could adapt it for your plugin:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel, QTableView

layer = iface.activeLayer()
features = layer.getFeatures()
model3 = QStandardItemModel()
model3.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, QStandardItem('Department'))
model3.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, QStandardItem('Code'))
for feature in features:
    item = QStandardItem(str(feature['name_dept'])), QStandardItem(str(feature['code']))
    model3.appendRow(item)

view = QTableView()
view.setModel(model3)
view.show()
```

Comment: is there any possibility to set items chekables ?

Comment: @zak - Yes, add `item[0].setCheckable(True)` after the line `item = QStandardItem(...)` to make the first column checkable.

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks a lot

Comment: @zak - Most welcome, glad it helped :)